# fasmg: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: fasm, z80

I am trying to convert my ez80 program to .8xp for my ti 83 premium ce with fasmg and the ez80-lib but i got the following error when trying to compile :

```
INCLUDE="include;include/fasmg-ez80" fasmg  DragonLairTI.asm DragonLairTI.8xp
/bin/sh: /c/Program Files (x86)/fasmg/fasmg: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
make: *** [Makefile:28: DragonLairTI.8xp] Error 126
```

The makefile is simple :

```
INCLUDES = $(addprefix include/,$(addprefix fasmg-ez80/,ez80.inc commands.alm ez80.alm) ti84pceg.inc)
all: DragonLairTI
unprot: FASMG_FLAGS = -i "protected equ"
unprot: all
$(MV) DragonLairTI.8xp
$(MAKE)
$(ZIP) DragonLairTI.zip DragonLairTI.8xp
%.8xp: %.asm $(INCLUDES) Makefile
INCLUDE="include;include/fasmg-ez80" $(FASMG) $(FASMG_FLAGS) $< $@
include/ti84pceg.inc: include/ti84pce.inc Makefile
include/fasmg-ez80/ti84pce.sed $< > $@
$(SED) --expression='3s/^/element anovaf_vars\n/' --in-place $@
include/ti84pce.inc: include/fasmg-ez80/bin/fetch_ti84pce Makefile
$(MKDIR) include
$(CD) include && fasmg-ez80/bin/fetch_ti84pce
```

Any idea how can i fix it ?

If you want to recreate the bug , i tried , you can use the app of the creator of the ez80 lib : https://github.com/jacobly0/asmhook

Comment: "Program files (x86)" so this is on Windows, but "Exec format error", which is kinda Linuxy. So you are running under WSL? 32/64 bit mismatch? [Yep, I think we have a winner](https://superuser.com/questions/1407730/run-32-bit-application-on-ubuntu-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux). Try running `fasmg.x64` instead.

Comment: Problem : the version is `.x64` or `.exe` and i am on windows . idk how i can execute `.x64` on windows

Comment: https://github.com/tgrysztar/fasmg/tree/master/core < - I see fasmg (Linux 32), fasmg.x64 (Linux 64) and fasmg.exe (Windows). You seem to be running the one of the three that doesn't work on your system. The other two executables should work.

Comment: (or just copy fasmg.x64 over fasmg and try again)

Comment: still not working, any idea how i can fix that ?

Comment: Did you try to use "fasmg.exe" instead of "fasmg"?

Comment: not working sorry